# How can I iterate over this object to to get a new object?

Tags: javascript, loops

I am relatively new to Javascript, and just learned basic for loops and for in loops. How can I iterate over this object to get certain keys and values? there are a bunch of nested objects in objects, so i am kind of confused. I was thinking of using some sort of "Object...()" method, but not sure which one to use.

desired output outcome is an object with the given champion key, followed by the champion id/name = `{"266": "Aatrox", "103" : "Ahri"}`

example input below

````
  "type": "champion",
  "format": "standAloneComplex",
  "version": "10.16.1",
  "data": {
    "Aatrox": {
      "version": "10.16.1",
      "id": "Aatrox",
      "key": "266",
      "name": "Aatrox",
      "title": "the Darkin Blade",
      "blurb": "Once honored defenders of Shurima against the Void, Aatrox and his brethren would eventually become an even greater threat to Runeterra, and were defeated only by cunning mortal sorcery. But after centuries of imprisonment, Aatrox was the first to find...",
      "info": {
        "attack": 8,
        "defense": 4,
        "magic": 3,
        "difficulty": 4
      },
      "image": {
        "full": "Aatrox.png",
        "sprite": "champion0.png",
        "group": "champion",
        "x": 0,
        "y": 0,
        "w": 48,
        "h": 48
      },
      "tags": [
        "Fighter",
        "Tank"
      ],
      "partype": "Blood Well",
      "stats": {
        "hp": 580,
        "hpperlevel": 90,
        "mp": 0,
        "mpperlevel": 0,
        "movespeed": 345,
        "armor": 38,
        "armorperlevel": 3.25,
        "spellblock": 32.1,
        "spellblockperlevel": 1.25,
        "attackrange": 175,
        "hpregen": 3,
        "hpregenperlevel": 1,
        "mpregen": 0,
        "mpregenperlevel": 0,
        "crit": 0,
        "critperlevel": 0,
        "attackdamage": 60,
        "attackdamageperlevel": 5,
        "attackspeedperlevel": 2.5,
        "attackspeed": 0.651
      }
    },
    "Ahri": {
      "version": "10.16.1",
      "id": "Ahri",
      "key": "103",
      "name": "Ahri",
      "title": "the Nine-Tailed Fox",
      "blurb": "Innately connected to the latent power of Runeterra, Ahri is a vastaya who can reshape magic into orbs of raw energy. She revels in toying with her prey by manipulating their emotions before devouring their life essence. Despite her predatory nature...",
      "info": {
        "attack": 3,
        "defense": 4,
        "magic": 8,
        "difficulty": 5
      },
      "image": {
        "full": "Ahri.png",
        "sprite": "champion0.png",
        "group": "champion",
        "x": 48,
        "y": 0,
        "w": 48,
        "h": 48
      },
      "tags": [
        "Mage",
        "Assassin"
      ],
      "partype": "Mana",
      "stats": {
        "hp": 526,
        "hpperlevel": 92,
        "mp": 418,
        "mpperlevel": 25,
        "movespeed": 330,
        "armor": 20.88,
        "armorperlevel": 3.5,
        "spellblock": 30,
        "spellblockperlevel": 0.5,
        "attackrange": 550,
        "hpregen": 6.5,
        "hpregenperlevel": 0.6,
        "mpregen": 8,
        "mpregenperlevel": 0.8,
        "crit": 0,
        "critperlevel": 0,
        "attackdamage": 53.04,
        "attackdamageperlevel": 3,
        "attackspeedperlevel": 2,
        "attackspeed": 0.668
      }
    }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Sam',
  old: 30,
  nested: {
    data: 'ABC',
    time: '3:15'
  }
}

for(let i in obj){
  console.log(i); //returns values
  console.log(obj[i]); //returns keys
  for(let j in obj[i]){
    console.log(j); //returns values of nested 2d level
    console.log(obj[i][j]); //returns keys of nested 2d level
  }
}
```